# +r +ggplot +jpeg +backgroud +transparent

Tags: r, ggplot2, background, transparency, ggsave

I'm trying to create a jpeg of a plot with a transparent background. I want to use the jpeg in powerpoint. I cannot get the transparency to work.  When I insert the jpeg into a ppt, it still has a white background. Are there options I am missing?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
library(gridExtra)
```

```
df<-data.frame(x=1:5)
df$y<-df$x**2

pl<-ggplot(df,aes(x=x,y=x)) +
     geom_point()
pl
```

```
pl_for_jpeg<-pl+
   theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        plot.margin = unit(c(0,0,0,0),'mm'),
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent", color=NA),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        plot.background =  element_rect(fill = "transparent", color=NA),
        
   )

pl_for_jpeg

ggsave("pl.jpeg",pl_for_jpeg,width=10, height = 7.5, units = "in",bg = "transparent")
```

Comment: Hello Rich, welcome to StackOverflow. As far as I know, `jpg` can't contain transparency. [link] https://www.quora.com/Can-a-JPEG-image-have-a-transparent-background?share=1

Comment: Alexis-thanks, that explains it.  A png format will do the trick for me.

Answer (score 2):

This should be the answer:

```
ggsave("pl.png",pl_for_jpeg,width=10, height = 7.5, units = "in",bg = "transparent")
```

Just have to change the extension to `png` for example and voila! You'll se your graphic with a transparent background on a ppt.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You aren't missing anything, the problem is with jpeg files: the format is made for photography, hence the files are usually square without backgroung transparency. Changing to another raster file format (like `.png`) or to a vector file (like `.svg`) should solve the problem.

In [`ggsave()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ggplot2/versions/3.3.2/topics/ggsave), you just need to change the file extension. Alternatively, in base R, you can use the [`png()`, `tiff()`, or `bmp()` functions](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/grDevices/versions/3.4.1/topics/png).